# CSS % widths not adding up to 100%, discrepancy seems to scale with font size

Tags: html, css

Does anyone have any idea why two blocks with 48% widths and 4% total horizontal margins wouldn't fit onto the same line without wrapping? Something simple like:

```
<div style="width: 500px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
   <div style="width: 48%; margin: 0 0 0 2%; padding: 0; background-color: red; display: inline-block;">A</div>
   <div style="width: 48%; margin: 0 0 0 2%; padding: 0; background-color: red; display: inline-block;">B</div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MikeHartman/cMHgE/)

It's been driving me crazy, and it happens across Firefox, Chrome and IE8. Windows and Linux.

At my standard zoom setting I can get them on the same line using "width: 47.5%". And I could live with that if it was consistent, but at my minimum zoom it needs to be 47.8% and at my maximum zoom it needs to be 46.5%. So I can't get a consistent whitespace alignment with other elements on my page across all zooms.

I initially assumed it was just a rounding error, but since the fudge factor seems to be dependent on font size there's got to be more to it. I can probably find some way to make my page look ok anyway, but I really want to know why it's doing this. It's going to keep me up tonight.

Comment: Make each block 50% and use padding instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the white spaces between the divs that are making up the extra space. Since these divs are inline-block the white spaces around them are rendered

```
<div class="should_fit">A</div><div class="should_fit">B</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cMHgE/4/

Comment: THANK YOU! Ugh, that's pretty HTML 101 too. I am suitably chastened.

Answer (score 1):

Set the parent element to

```
white-space: nowrap
```